# What does the this Windows 10 Action Center tray icon overlay indicate, exactly?

Tags: windows-10, icons, action-center

Here is a screenshot, containing the icon (the one in the middle, presumably describing a text note, with what looks as a stop sign at lower right corner of it):

[image: A screenshot of the end portion of Windows 10 taskbar, showing, among other familiar icons, the Action Center icon resembling a scribbled note with a stop sign at its lower right corner]

I cannot find explanation on what is being communicated to me here? Most of the time the icon **does not** have the stop sign overlay there, but regardless of this, clicking on it simply gives me the Action Center pane that says "No new notifications".

So, what could that overlay indicate? I am not the worrying type, but I am an IT specialist, so I want to know what's going on.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It indicated Quiet hours enabled (even if you didnt enable them = bug). Turn on and off Quiet hours and icon should disappear.

Answer (score 1):

The stop kind of symbol on the Action center originally means Quiet Hours are enabled. so if your PC shows that symbol even if the Quite hours are not enabled, then try enable and disable it. it should solve your problem. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

It means there are no new notifications. It took me a while to put it together, myself.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/485361)

Comment: @Ramhound aren't you being quite overly pedantic? I am the author of the question, and even though arguably an "incorrect" answer, it is useful in itself. In my opinion it *does*, in fact, provide an answer to my question. Since there is no documentation provided by Microsoft that is made available to me, any answer may be correct. I chose another, because I understood it, but I understand what Chris is saying as well.

Comment: @amn - This answer appeared in the review queue for a reason.  I am not alone in the believe this answer is more comment then an actual answer.  **"JakeGould reviewed this Jan 10 at 23:56: Recommend Deletion"**

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue and tried the answer above and it didn't take care of my issue. I don't doubt that this is a bug with the new windows action center, but what fixed it for me was turning on notifications. I didn't know that they had gotten disabled, but I right-clicked the action center, clicked on turn on notifications and the symbol went away.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).